# How can I unsubscribe from Observable/Subject on the first emission while defining the observer

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs-observables

I am working on some dialogs with angular 9 and I came into a situation where I need to unsubscribe from a Subject after the first emission.

Initially, I thought of piping the subject using the `take(1)` or `first()` operator and subscribe to this "transformed finite subject". So the unsubscription will be handled automatically just after the first emissions ocurrs, because when an observable completes the unsubscription logic is called. Example:

```js
const subject = new Subject();

subject.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(console.log);

subject.next("hola");
```

But then I have also found this "hack" that I think its also working, can someone confirm?

```js
const subject = new Subject();

const subscription = subject.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  subscription.unsubscribe(); // <----- this is the magic line
}

subject.next("hola");
```

I have never seen this before, I think its convenient in some occasions. The thing that confused me is that the observer is calling the subscription defined in the same line. Is this good practice? Is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first()` or `take(1)`. both unsubscribe automatically when their condition is met.

```
const { Subject } = require('rxjs/');
const { take, first } = require('rxjs/operators');

const subject = new Subject();

subject.pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
  console.log({ data });
});

subject.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
  console.log({ data });
});
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, what do you think of the second method I propossed?

Comment: I prefer first one.
why you unsubscribe manually while you can unsubscribe automatic?